# Having trouble looping through os.walk(./)

Tags: python, operating-system

I am trying to make a script which loops through the current directory and checks for each file if it has a clone(The copy of the same file). Here's the code:

```
import os
import filecmp

scan_result = os.walk("./")
checked_files = []

for parent, dirs, files in scan_result:
    for file in files:
        file = parent + "\\" + file
        checked_files.append(file)

        for par, d, f in scan_result:
            for fi in f:
                data = par + "\\" + fi 

                if data not in checked_files:
                    result = filecmp.cmp(file, data)
                    print(f"Comparing {file} with {data}")

                    if result:
                        print(f"Dupe Found for {file} and {data}")
                    else:
                        print(f"No luck for the file {file} with {data}")
```

But whenever I run the code the script only checks one file in the same folder without actually going into any other directories and ends abruptly. Any solution to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you looping over `scan_result` again inside the main loop where you are already iterating over it?

Comment: @JohnGordon I am doing that so I can see if the file has any form of clone inside it's sub directories

Comment: `os.walk` is a generator. It cannot be iterated on multiple times. Since you are trying to iterate over it in 2 different loops, it's not processing all the results properly

Comment: @rdas Oh I completely forgot its a generator object, is there any work around for that

Comment: `scan_result = list(os.walk('./'))`

Comment: @rdas So list objects can be iterated around multiple times right, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thanking @rdas for answering this question in the comments. os.walk() returns a generator object, so when I tried to iterate through that object twice in the same code, the iterator completely skips over all the directories. The simple solution to this problem is to just replace this line of code

```
scan_result = os.walk("./")
```

with

```
scan_result = list(os.walk("./"))
```